# SDL Memory leak with TTF_Font and surface

Tags: c++, sdl

I am creating 2D game with SDL2, and I have a problem with my label class. 
Every time I construct new label I have a memory leak, and I don't know what I do wrong!
For example, I want to refresh every time the fps label on my game, I have a memory leak since the old texture seems that doesn't deletes.
Here is the code of the Label class. Tell me please where I am wrong!

```
namespace se {

class WidgetLabel : public Widget {
public:
    WidgetLabel(std::shared_ptr<Display> t_display,const Vector2i& t_possition, const std::string& t_text, const int t_fontSize = 25, const Color& t_color = Color(255,255,255,255));
    WidgetLabel(const WidgetLabel& rhs) = delete;
    WidgetLabel& operator =(const WidgetLabel& rhs) = delete;
    ~WidgetLabel();
    void render();
    void update();
    void setBlendMode(SDL_BlendMode t_blending);
    void setAlphaMode(Uint8 t_alpha);

    void setPossition(const Vector2i& t_possitions);
    void setPossitionX(const int t_x);
    void setPossitionY(const int t_y);
    const Vector2i getPossition() const;
    void setFontPath(const std::string& t_path);
    void setText(const std::string& t_string);
    const Vector2i getResolution() const;
    int getWidth() const;
    int getHeight() const;

private:

    std::shared_ptr<Display>    m_display;
    TTF_Font                    *m_font;
    SDL_Surface                 *m_surface;
    SDL_Texture                 *m_texture;

    int                         m_width;
    int                         m_height;
    int                         m_possitionX;
    int                         m_possitionY;


    std::string                 m_text;
    int                         m_fontSize;
    std::string                 m_fontPath;
    Color                       m_color;

    void createSurface();

};
```

}

```
namespace se {

WidgetLabel::WidgetLabel(std::shared_ptr<Display> t_display,const Vector2i& t_possition, const std::string& t_text, const int t_fontSize, const Color& t_color) :
m_display(t_display),
m_surface(nullptr),
m_texture(nullptr),
m_width(0),
m_height(0),
m_possitionX(t_possition.getX()),
m_possitionY(t_possition.getY()),
m_text(t_text),
m_fontSize(t_fontSize),
m_fontPath("assets/fonts/serif.ttf"),
m_color(t_color)

{

    m_font = TTF_OpenFont(m_fontPath.c_str(), t_fontSize);

    if (m_font == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Faild to load SDL Font! Error: " << TTF_GetError() << '\n';
    }

    int imgflags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if ( !( IMG_Init(imgflags) & imgflags)) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't not initialize sdl image" << '\n';
    }

    createSurface();

}

WidgetLabel::~WidgetLabel()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
    m_texture = nullptr;
}

void WidgetLabel::render()
{
    SDL_Rect rect_ = { m_possitionX, m_possitionY, m_width, m_height};
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(m_display->getRenderer(), m_texture, nullptr, &rect_, 0.0, nullptr, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
void WidgetLabel::setPossition(const Vector2i &t_possitions)
{
    m_possitionX = t_possitions.getX();
    m_possitionY = t_possitions.getY();
}

void WidgetLabel::setPossitionX(const int t_x)
{
    m_possitionX = t_x;
}
void WidgetLabel::setPossitionY(const int t_y)
{
    m_possitionY = t_y;
}
const Vector2i WidgetLabel::getPossition() const
{
    return Vector2i(m_possitionX, m_possitionY);
}

void WidgetLabel::setFontPath(const std::string &t_path)
{
    m_fontPath = t_path;
}
void WidgetLabel::setText(const std::string &t_string)
{
    m_text = t_string;
    createSurface();
}
void WidgetLabel::createSurface()
{

    m_surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(m_font, m_text.c_str(), m_color);

    if ( m_surface == nullptr ) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to render text surface! Error: " << TTF_GetError() << '\n';
    } else {

        m_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_display->getRenderer(), m_surface);

        if ( m_texture == nullptr ) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to create texture from renderer text! Error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
        } else {

            m_width = m_surface->w;
            m_height = m_surface->h;

        }

        SDL_FreeSurface(m_surface);
        m_surface = nullptr;
    }

}
const Vector2i WidgetLabel::getResolution() const
{
    return Vector2i(m_width, m_height);
}

int WidgetLabel::getWidth() const
{
    return m_width;
}

int WidgetLabel::getHeight() const
{
    return m_height;
}
void WidgetLabel::update()
{

}

void WidgetLabel::setBlendMode(SDL_BlendMode t_blending)
{
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(m_texture, t_blending);
}

void WidgetLabel::setAlphaMode(Uint8 t_alpha)
{
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(m_texture, t_alpha);
}
```

}

The render and update function called in main game loop. 
The shared pointer with t_display, is just the passed renderer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon first glance, it looks like you call `TTF_OpenFont` to create your font in your label constructor, but you do not call `TTF_CloseFont` in the destructor. You should.

You also call `createSurface` in both the constructor and `setText`. When called from `setText`, `createSurface` will immediately allocate a new `m_surface` and `m_texture`, causing you to lose the things they were previously pointing at (and thus, leak them).

If you're going to use that model, you probably need `createSurface` to first check if the texture is non-null, and if so, release it prior to creating a new one. It's not clear that `m_surface` needs to be member at all since it appears you only create it for `createSurface` and always release it before the function ends. It may simplify your code if you can just make that surface a temporary local.

Comment: every time i use TTF_CloseFont i get this error from compiler: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: Well, that is interesting but probably a different bug (maybe you are corrupting the font pointer or font data with a memory overwrite somewhere?). The fact is, however, that if you call TTF_OpenFont you should pair it with TTF_CloseFont to free the memory used by the font.

Comment: A quick search suggests that if your destructor is firing after TTF_Quit gets called, and you call TTF_Close in your destructor, you will crash (since TTF_Quit means you can no longer call most TTF_ functions). I'd step through in your debugger to see if that is the case.

Comment: Ok, seems the problem is caused by TTF_Quit(); 
since i remove TTF_Quit(); everything is works fine !

Comment: You probably want TTF_Quit as well, just make sure all your widget labels get destroyed *before* you call it.

Comment: hmm it's kinda strange, since ttf_quit is called with sdl_quit, at then end , but i still get error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42848/discussion-between-ro-stel-and-josh-petrie).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I have no memory leak now steady a steady line

so in my update drawing the renderer // SDL_Surface* surface is in my header and gets deleted on the ~destructor

```
if (surface == NULL) {
    surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(getFont(), getText(), getColor());
    setMessage(SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(getRender(), surface));
}

SDL_RenderCopy(getRender(), getMessage(), NULL, getMousePosition());

if (surface != NULL)
{
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, surface, NULL);
    //SDL_FreeSurface(surface); // dont destroy

}
else
{
    // report error
}
```